# How to show $\int_{\mathbb{C}}|f(z)|^2(1+|z|)^{-\alpha}dV(z) <\infty$ and $f$ entire then $f$ is a polynomial

Tags: complex-analysis

I read in a textbook and see the following problem:

Let $f:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be an entire function such that for some  $\alpha >0$, we have
$$\int_{\mathbb{C}}|f(z)|^2(1+|z|)^{-\alpha}dxdy <\infty.$$
Then $f$ is a polynomial.

I don't know how to verify this. In order to prove that $f$ is a polynomial we need to show that $f^{(n)}\equiv 0$ for some $n\in \mathbb{N}$. I think Liouville theorem might help but I have no idea.

Could anyone give me a hint how to relate am integral inequality with a certain estimate on the derivative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f(z)=\sum a_nz^n$ and note that for $0 \le |z| \le R$ we have $(1+|z|)^{-\alpha} \ge (1+|R|)^{-\alpha}$ so:

$I=\int_{\mathbb{C}}|f(z)|^2(1+|z|)^{-\alpha}dV(z) \ge (1+|R|)^{-\alpha}\int_{|z| \le R}|f(z)|^2dV(z) =$

$=(1+|R|)^{-\alpha}\int_0^R\int_0^{2\pi}(\sum a_nr^ne^{in\theta})(\sum \bar a_n r^ne^{-in\theta})rd\theta dr=$

$=2\pi (1+|R|)^{-\alpha} \sum_{n \ge 0}\frac{|a_n|^2R^{2n+2}}{2n+2}$

(noting that we can switch series and integral by uniform convergence and that non-diagonal terms integrate to zero $d\theta$)

The hypothesis implies:

$2\pi (1+|R|)^{-\alpha} \sum_{n \ge 0}\frac{|a_n|^2R^{2n+2}}{2n+2} \le I < \infty$

Letting $R \to \infty$ we immediately get that $a_n=0$ if $2n+2- \alpha >0$ so $f$ must be a polynomial with degree at most $\frac{\alpha-2}{2}$ if that is nonnegative (or $f$ identically zero otherwise)

Comment: Your answer is very clear.